# Is it possible to know which image display in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have two images. I used ViewPager to display them individually. I want to know which ones is displaying in the screen. Could you help me to solve it? For example, when I scroll the screen, the first image will display and Toast a message such as "This is first image", do same thing for second image. Thanks in advance. This is my code

```
public class ViewPagerExample extends FragmentActivity{

    private MyAdapter mAdapter;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
    {
    return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.image1);
    }
    case 1:
    {
    return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.image2);
    }

    default:
    return null;
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

and the ImageFragment class

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
    private final int imageResourceId;

    public ImageFragment(int imageResourceId) {
    this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.e("Test", "hello");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_layout, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageResourceId);
    return view;
    }
    }
```

Comment: set page change listener on ViewPager.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int pager_position) {

                // show toast here for images
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: It worked well. But for first time, what I did not click on the screen, the toast does not show anything, while, the screen is showing the first image. Has any way to display it

Comment: you can display toast as you populate data in view pager... because you are implementing page change listener and on start there is no page changed that's why it is not showing any toast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these lines of code to detect the image on swipe

```
    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);


            System.out.println("Positoin is the=="+position);

            if(position==0)
            {
                ///on the zero position you can get the image
            }
            else
            {
                ///on the first position you can get the image                  
            }

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method   `yourViewpagerObject.getCurrentItem()`   which returns the position of currently Viewed page of view pager